# ReferenceError: $firebase is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit test this service using jasmine:-

my unit test is :-

```
describe('initial configuration for the test user', function () {

  beforeEach(function(){
      var config = {
            'Apache 404' : {
              content : {
                type : 'tip',
                template : 'yesNo',
                text : 'Are you searching for status code 404?',
                yesText : 'Try our more accurate <a href="https://www.loggly.com/docs/search-query-language/#field_names" target="_blank">field search</a>',
                attachTo : '#inputBox right',
                yesActions : {
                  0 : {
                      type : 'replaceSubstring',
                      target : '#inputBox',
                      value : 'apache.status:404',
                      match : '404'
                    }
                }
              },
              conditions : {
                0 : {
                    type : 'valueChange',
                    target : '#inputBox',
                    textMatch : '(^|([\\s]+))404(([\\s]+)|$)',
                    preventSubmit : true
                  },
                1 : {
                    type : 'contentPropertyLessThan',
                    propertyName : 'timesShown',
                    compareVal : 3
                  }
              }
            }
      };

      var clientName = 'testClient';
      var fireRef = new Firebase('https://luminous-inferno-1740.firebaseio.com/' + clientName);
      var fireSync = $firebase(fireRef);
      fireSync.$set({'config' : config});
      log.message = 'Resetting user data';
      $log.debug(log);

      userData.init(function(done) {
          done();
        });
  });

  it('should have a valid config', function () {
      expect(Object.keys(userData.getConfig()).length > 1);
    });
```

});

I am receiving an error :-

> ReferenceError: $firebase is not defined
>       at Object.

Can somebody help me providing working example of my code with some explanation?

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/161 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731658/angularjs-error-unknown-provider-angularfireprovider-angularfire

Comment: To append to Frank's thoughts, like any other Angular service, you need to inject it. This is done using inject() in the test code.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem. I solved my problem by adding $firebaseArray in the parameter of the controller

**.controller('ChatsCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray','$rootScope',......**

One thing should be noted that firebase has been updated that $firebase is no longer supported. You can only use $firebaseArray or $firebaseObject for retrieving the data.